# JSON financial protocol?

Tags: json, protocols, financial, fpml

Does a json financial protocol exist?

I've seen FIX, FpML, and SWIFT, but none seem to have a json version.

Is there a protocol in existence no matter how experimental that relies upon JSON or something else human readable & lightweight?

If so, what is it?

Comment: There seems to have be a conversion discussed here,
http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/pg/discussions/topicpost/169912/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No.
There is clearly a [push for it](http://www.fpml.org/asset/9820d2a0/e7640790.pdf) but so far validation tools have the upper hand on legibility.